# Angular $http requests not fulfilling in Promise.all

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a array of http requests that I am using in an `Promise.all`. The issue is that when `Promise.all` is fulfilled, `console.log(values);` shows the original `dealers` array instead of the resolved http requests response object. Why am I not getting the resolved http requests in the `Promise.all`?

```
  function getDealer(regionMarketDealer) {
    var params = {
      url: API_BASE_URI + 'service/ppv/' + regionMarketDealer,
      method: 'GET'
    };

    return $http(params);
  }

function getAllMarketDealers(dealers) {
  var dealerHttpRequests = dealers.filter(function(dealer) {
    if (dealer.name !== 'All') {
      var promise = getDealer(dealer.name);
      return promise;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  Promise.all([dealerHttpRequests])
    .then(function(values) {
      console.log(values);
    });
}
```

Comment: You've got an array of arrays in there?

Comment: ya, I realized that and removed the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.filter is used to filter your array by returning true or false in a function and that then creates a new array with the filtered result.

If you then want to create promises of the filtered array you should then use .map and return a promise

```
function getDealer(regionMarketDealer) {
    var params = {
      url: API_BASE_URI + 'service/ppv/' + regionMarketDealer,
      method: 'GET'
    };

    return $http(params);
  }

function getAllMarketDealers(dealers) {
  var dealerHttpRequests = dealers.filter(function(dealer) {
        return dealer.name !== 'All';
    })
    .map(function(dealer) {
        return getDealer(dealer.name);
    });

  Promise.all(dealerHttpRequests)
    .then(function(values) {
      console.log(values);
    });
}
```